# How to redirect if an argument missing from controller method?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Suppose I am creating a dynamic file and I will pass variable inside `method_name($variable)` and $variable having name ("abc") then our path look like for example:

http://localhost/folder_name/index.php/controller_name/method_name/abc

If I remove abc from the following path then url will look like http://localhost/folder_name/index.php/controller_name/method_name/

and then we run on browser then it will show error i.e.

> Message: Missing argument 1 for method_name::controller_name().

So, My question is how to redirect a file if variable value is remove from method. I want to redirect a file to controller if method having nothing inside it.

Thank You

Comment: i didn't understand. please calrify if variable is not passed then what you want? redirect to another controller?

Comment: Just set a default value: `method_name($variable = null)` and redirect if the variable is null. Btw. Shouldn't it be `controller_name::method_name()`?

Comment: No, I am not saying that variable is not passed simply If I remove variable value from url and then run it will show error Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for controller::method_name() @M.sulemanKhan

Comment: @omkara That's because the variable isn't passed to the method (hence the error message telling you exact that). Either way, you have an answer that should work for you.

Comment: @omkara what do you mean by redirect a file?

Comment: ok,  then how to fix this problem @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Check argument

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($abc = NULL)
    {
         if($abc){
            // IF argument 
            echo 'Hello World!';
         }else{
            // Redirect here if not argument parsed
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sun eel Kumar

Comment: @omkara Your Welcome